# Self-hosted WCF REST app requires password for “OPTIONS” pre-flight request

Tags: wcf, cors

I have a self-hosted WCF application (mixed C#, C++) that provides a REST based API, to be accessed by a web client.

I have implemented CORS to support the OPTIONS request, and this appears to work if I have no authorization enabled.

However, if I enable basic authorization, I get `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` and `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""` results.

How id I disable authorization for the OPTION command

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicSecurity" maxBufferSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000000" maxStringContentLength="65535"/>
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="JustMetaData" name="soapcon.SimpleContract">
                <endpoint address="https://localhost:8888/Simple" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicSecurity" name="SimpleContract" contract="soapcon.ISimpleContract" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8888/Simple"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                    <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="soapcon.EnableCorsBehavior, server_console, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::ServiceModel::Channels;
using namespace System::ServiceModel::Dispatcher;
using namespace System::ServiceModel::Description;
using namespace System::ServiceModel::Configuration;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

// See https://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html

namespace soapcon
{
    public ref class CustomHeaderMessageInspector : public IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        Dictionary<System::String^, System::String^>^ requiredHeaders;

    public:
        CustomHeaderMessageInspector(Dictionary<System::String^, System::String^>^ headers)
        {
            if (headers)
                requiredHeaders = headers;
            else
                requiredHeaders = gcnew Dictionary<System::String^, System::String^>();
        }

        virtual System::Object^ AfterReceiveRequest(System::ServiceModel::Channels::Message^% request, System::ServiceModel::IClientChannel^ channel, System::ServiceModel::InstanceContext^ instanceContext)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        virtual void BeforeSendReply(System::ServiceModel::Channels::Message^% reply, System::Object^ correlationState)
        {
            if (!reply->Properties->ContainsKey("httpResponse"))
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty ^httpProp = gcnew HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                reply->Properties->Add("httpResponse", httpProp);
            }
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty^ httpHeader = dynamic_cast<HttpResponseMessageProperty^>(reply->Properties["httpResponse"]);
                for each (auto item in requiredHeaders)
                {
                    httpHeader->Headers->Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    public ref class EnableCorsBehavior : public BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
    {
    public:
        // IEndpointBehavior
        virtual void Validate(System::ServiceModel::Description::ServiceEndpoint^)
        {
        }

        virtual void AddBindingParameters(System::ServiceModel::Description::ServiceEndpoint^, System::ServiceModel::Channels::BindingParameterCollection^)
        {
        }

        virtual void ApplyDispatchBehavior(System::ServiceModel::Description::ServiceEndpoint^, System::ServiceModel::Dispatcher::EndpointDispatcher^ endpointDispatcher)
        {
            auto requiredHeaders = gcnew Dictionary<System::String^, System::String^>();

            requiredHeaders->Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            requiredHeaders->Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            requiredHeaders->Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Api-Key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Cache-Control");
            endpointDispatcher->DispatchRuntime->MessageInspectors->Add(gcnew CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders));
        }

        virtual void ApplyClientBehavior(System::ServiceModel::Description::ServiceEndpoint^, System::ServiceModel::Dispatcher::ClientRuntime^)
        {
        }

        // BehaviorExtensionElement
        property System::Type^ BehaviorType
        {
            System::Type^ get() override { return EnableCorsBehavior::typeid; }
        };

        System::Object^ CreateBehavior() override
        {
            return gcnew EnableCorsBehavior();
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a CORS middleware must come before any authentication middleware. CORS-preflight requests indeed do not carry any credentials.